# Returning a result of true if all the individual characters of pattern appear in string

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a piece of JS code that returns a result of true if if pattern appears in string as a substring (case sensitive) but would like to extend its functionality to returns true if all the individual characters of pattern appear in string (regardless of order).

For example:

This is what the program currently does:

```
match1("adipisci","pis") returns true
```

Whereas I would now like it to do this:

```
match1("adipisci","sciip") returns true
match2("adipisci","sciipx") returns false because x does not exist in variable
```

I am having difficulty implementing this into my code:

```
var pages=[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
  "Nulla imperdiet laoreet neque.",
  "Praesent at gravida nisl. Quisque tincidunt, est ac porta malesuada, augue lorem posuere lacus, vitae commodo purus nunc et lacus."
  ];
var search_term = prompt('Type in search term: ','Search word');
// ask which search term the user wants to search for with default being 'Search Term' 
function find_s(w) {
    var indexes = [0,0,0] // create an array  to hold pages where search term found
    var iii = 0 // create variable to increment the number of finds in each page
    for (var ii=0;ii<pages.length;ii++) {
    // for each page in the array
        for (var i=0;i<pages[ii].length;i++) {
        // for each character in the chosen page
            if (pages[ii].substr(i,w.length).toLowerCase()==w.substr(0,w.length).toLowerCase()) {
            // check to see if the search term is there ignoring case
                iii++;
                // increment number of times the search term in found
                while(pages[ii].substr(i,1)!=" ") {
                    // move to the next word but checking for spaces
                    i++;
                    }
            }
        }
        indexes[ii]=iii;
        // update the number of times the search term is found in that page
        iii=0;
        // reset counter for next page search
    }
    return (w + " was found in this may times in each page " + indexes);
    // let the user know the result
}
alert (find_s(search_term));
```

I would appreciate any guidance into the right direction - thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to achieve what you expect is the following function:

```
var containsChars = function(where, what){
    var containsChar = function(where, what){
        return !!(where.indexOf(what)+1);
    }    
    var allChars = what.split('');
    for (var i=0; i<allChars.length; i++){
        if (!containsChar(where, allChars[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As a proof, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUQ4u/).

I have intentionally separated function `containsChar()` so it is easier for you to change the way chars are compared (depending whether you want them to be compared in case sensitive or case insensitive way).

Comment: `var allChars = what.split('');` - what does the line do?

Comment: @jeansymolanza: This line splits string (variable named "`what`") into individual chars (`split()` method works that way if passed empty string `''` as parameter) and saves them as array variable named "`allChars`". Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you whether all chars in `needles` are present in `haystack` or not.

```
var match1 = function(haystack, needles) {
    var chars = needles.split('');

    for (var i = 0, length = chars.length; i < length; i++) {
       if (haystack.indexOf(chars[i]) === -1) {
           return false;
       }
    }

    return true;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vD2g5/).

Comment: `var chars = needles.split('');` what does this line do?

Comment: @jeansymolanza It splits the individual characters of a string into an array.

Answer (score 1):

A function like this oughta do the trick:

```
function allChars(lookIn, lookFor) {
   for(var i = 0; i < lookFor.length; ++i) {
      var c = lookFor.charAt(i);
      if(lookIn.indexOf(c) == -1)
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Why does it return the output in reverse order?

Comment: This function only returns `true` or `false`. It shouldn't return any "output".

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < search_term.length; ++i) {
            var c = search_term.charAt(i);    
              if(pages.indexOf(c) == -1)
            alert(false);
             }
            alert(true);
            }`

Comment: @jeansymolanza alert is not the same as return.  If you want it to alert, you still need the return statement.  E.g. alert(false); return;

Comment: Do we need a return statement in all functions?

Comment: No. Only in functions where you want the return value. If a function doesn't have a return statement, it's value when called is `undefined`

Comment: @jeansymolanza & @BryanRoss: There is also one additional reason for `return` statement: `return` statement stops execution of the function (because result has been provided), thus it will not reach `return true;` if it has reached `return false;`. This way if some character was not found, the function will not return `true` (because will not reach that statement). But these are programming basics.